linux sys/shm.h latency can be 20us?
I want to exchange data between processes.
I choose shared memory, the reason is i think it's fastest IPC method.
But the following code tells different story.
string_worker.hpp: this is a base class, which ensure both reader and writer can create shm
#pragma once
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <error.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct Header {  // Header is visable for reader and writer, to know where is the last data position
  const int32_t size_;
  volatile int32_t tail_;  // writable for writer, read by reader
  Header(int32_t size, int32_t tail) : size_(size), tail_(tail) {}
  void Show(const std::string & tag = "") const { printf("%s size = %d, tail = %d\n", tag.c_str(), size_, tail_); }
};

class StringWorker {
 public:
  virtual ~StringWorker() {
    shmdt(m_data);
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0); 
  }

 protected:
  key_t get_keyid(const std::string & name) {  // name the shared memory
    const std::string & s = "./" + name;
    if (access(s.c_str(), F_OK) == -1) { const std::string & s1 = "touch " + s; system(s1.c_str()); }
    key_t semkey = ftok(name.c_str(), 1); 
    if (semkey == -1) { printf("shm_file:%s not existed\n", s.c_str()); exit(1); }
    return semkey;
  }

  void init(const std::string& name, int size) {  // create or connect to the shm
    key_t m_key = get_keyid(name);
    char * p = nullptr;
    shmid = shmget(m_key, 0, 0);  // TODO: check m_key existed
    if (shmid == -1) {
      if (errno != ENOENT && errno != EINVAL) {
        printf("errno is %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
      }   
      shmid = shmget(m_key, sizeof(Header) + 1024 * 64 * size, 0666 | IPC_CREAT | O_EXCL);
      if (shmid == -1) {
        printf("both connet and create are failed for shm\n");
        exit(1);
      }   
      p = (char*)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0); 
      printf("creating new shm %s %p\n", name.c_str(), p); 
      Header h(size, 0); 
      memcpy(p, &h, sizeof(Header));
    } else {
      p = (char*)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0); 
      printf("existed m_data = %p\n", p); 
    }   
    if (p == nullptr) {
      printf("shmat failed");
      exit(1);
    }   
    header_ = (Header*)p;
    m_data = p + sizeof(Header);
  }

  int shmid;
  char* m_data;
  Header* header_;
};

string_sender.hpp: sender
#pragma once
#include <mutex>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#include "./string_worker.hpp"

class StringSender: public StringWorker {
 public:
  StringSender(const std::string& key, int size = 4096) {
    init(key, size);
    tail_ = &header_->tail_;
  }

  void Send(const char * p, size_t size) {
    char * cur_data = m_data + *tail_ % header_->size_;
    memcpy(cur_data, p, size + 1);  // '\0'
    *tail_ += 1;
  }

 private:
  volatile int32_t * tail_;
};

int main() {
  timeval t;
  StringSender sender("a");
  std::string a;
  while (std::cin >> a && a != "quit") {
    sender.Send(a.data(), a.size());
    gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
    cout << a << " sent " << t.tv_usec << endl;
  }
}

string_recver.hpp: recver
#pragma once
#include "./string_worker.hpp"

class StringRecver : public StringWorker {
 public:
  StringRecver(const std::string & key, int size = 4096) {
    init(key, size);
    read_index_ = header_->tail_;
  }

  std::string_view Recv() {
    while (read_index_ == header_->tail_) {}
    read_index_ += 1;
    return m_data + read_index_ % header_->size_;
  }

 private:
  int32_t read_index_;
};

int main() {
  timeval t;
  StringRecver recver("a");
  while (true) {
    std::string_view a = recver.Recv();
    gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
    cout << "recv " << a << " " << t.tv_usec << endl;
  }
}

The complie command is:
#!/bin/bash
g++ -std=c++2a -O3 sender.cpp -o s
g++ -std=c++2a -O3 recver.cpp -o r

The output of these code is:
sender
existed m_data = 0x7f0612d08000
nasd
nasd sent 453488
asd
asd sent 989748
nasd
nasd sent 355481

recver
existed m_data = 0x7fa263818000
recv asd 453509
recv sd 989769
recv asd 355502

My machine cpu is:
Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10900K CPU @ 3.70GHz

From the ouput, we can know the latency between the send data and receive data cost about 20us. This is much higher than I thought, I assume it will be ns.
Could you help on this? Is there anything wrong in my code? or another solution advice is much appreicated.

Busy loops (while (read_index_ == header_->tail_) { }, gettimeofday, a mix of C and C++ . There's plenty of code here that's not wrong as in bug, but more wrong as in sub-optimal.

@MSalters could you provides some specific advice?

@kevein: Yes, don't reinvent the wheel. There's already Boost.Interprocess. The Boost libraries are field-tested and free.
